# React-Router (v3) not loading images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi I'm using `react router` to go around my web.

I used `create-react-app` to start my project.

Using `React@15.4.2, react-router@3.0.2`

One weird thing is happening; Image loads when manually refreshing, but fails to load when you navigate to different parts of web using nav bar.

Here's how I defined route:

```
Class App extends Component{
    render () {
      return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
          <Route path="create" component={Create}/>
          <Route path="login" component={Login}/>

        </Route>

      </Router>
    );
    }}
```

Here's Login Component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
     class Login extends Component{
     render () {
        return (
         <div>
           <div className="main-container">
             <section className="height-100 imagebg text-center" data-overlay="4">
                 <div className="background-image-holder">
                     <img alt="background" src='img/inner-6.jpg' />
                 </div>
                 <div className="container pos-vertical-center">
                     <div className="row">
                         <div className="col-sm-7 col-md-5">
                             <h2>Login to continue</h2>
                             <p className="lead">
                                 Welcome back, sign in with your existing Stack account credentials
                             </p>
                             <form>
                                 <div className="row">
                                     <div className="col-sm-12">
                                         <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="col-sm-12">
                                         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                     </div>
                                     <div className="col-sm-12">
                                         <button className="btn btn--primary type--uppercase" type="submit">Login</button>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>

                             </form>
                             <span className="type--fine-print block">Dont have an account yet?
                                 <a href="page-accounts-create-1.html">Create account</a>
                             </span>
                             <span className="type--fine-print block">Forgot your username or password?
                                 <a href="page-accounts-recover.html">Recover account</a>
                             </span>
                         </div>
                     </div>

                 </div>

             </section>
         </div>

      </div>
    );}}
   export default Login;
```

So i'm trying to load image `'inner-6.jpg'` as background image.

When I manually refresh the page on `Login` component, the picture loads fine, but when I route to, for example, `Create or Home,` then go back/click login on navbar, the image doesn't get loaded.

I tried loading image using;

```
src={require('./img/inner-6.jpg')}
```

but same thing happened.

The images in `{Main}` component does same thing.

Am I loading the images wrong?? if so, how come it loads when I manually refresh page?
 or am I routing wrong??

*Tried loading random image from web(http://tinypic.com/) with absolute path.
Same thing still happens